# Android Lollipop open Facebook intent give content not available

Tags: android, facebook, android-5.0-lollipop

I open Facebook through

```
public static Intent getOpenFacebookIntent(Context context) {

    try {
        context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0);
        return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://profile/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"));
    }
}
```

Calling it as:

```
fb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(getOpenFacebookIntent(context));
        }
    });
```

It works fine except for Lollipop where I get a white screen "Content not available".

Anyone know how I could fix it or had same issue?

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is this problem specific to Lollipop, or to the version of the Facebook app you're using on Lollipop?